# Laravel Join with JSON column in second table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

Table: **Staffs**

### id    |     name

### 1     |     staff 1

### 2     |     staff 2

2     |     staff 3

---

Table: **Salary**

### staffids    |     Scale

### [1,2]        |     1500

### [13]         |     3000

How do i write Below query in Laravel ( >= 6)

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.scale
FROM staffs a
LEFT JOIN salary s ON JSON_CONTAINS(a.id, JSON_QUOTE(b.staffids), '$')
```

Comment: sorry mate, I'm not familiar with architecture of your app, but it's not a good way for db, there is a good practice to have several such rows instead of one (read 1st normal form for database), so in such case you won't have such problems at all

Answer (score -1):

add use

```
use DB;
```

code is

```
$query = DB::table('Staffs')->join('Salary','Salary. staffids','Staffs.id')
->select('Staffs.id','Staffs.name','Scale')->get();
```

with model

```
$query = Staffs::join('Salary','Salary. staffids','Staffs.id')
    ->select('Staffs.id','Staffs.name','Scale')->get();
```

Comment: have you checked his question before posting the answer?